# Char limits for Push Notification on mobile app

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Is there any char limit on mobile app notification for IOS and Android. I am using the AWS SNS as service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation shows that the entire payload limit is 256kb:

1. [What is the maximum payload length of AWS SNS for mobile push notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898909/what-is-the-maximum-payload-length-of-aws-sns-for-mobile-push-notifications)
2. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/06/18/amazon-sqs-announces-256KB-large-payloads/